# how to create a pivot query using the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I wish to create a pivot using this data and have it look like this[image]

note how the model is value line 1 and revision value line 2 and value is value line 3 or in other words model = test_key_id 23, revision = test_key_id 25 and value = test_key_id 24
I was able to come up with this query:

```
BEGIN
        --this is a copy of the query above just for troubleshooting purposes
        with t1 as (
            SELECT test_recipe_id, LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) as model_num , row_number() over (order by id ) rn
            FROM [leakOpportunities].[dbo].[test_recipe_value] WHERE test_key_id in(23)
        ),
        t2 as (
            SELECT  test_recipe_id,LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) as value, row_number() over (order by id ) rn
            FROM [leakOpportunities].[dbo].[test_recipe_value] WHERE test_key_id in(24)
        ),
        t3 as (
            SELECT  test_recipe_id,LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) as revision, row_number() over (order by id ) rn
            FROM [leakOpportunities].[dbo].[test_recipe_value] WHERE test_key_id in(25)
        ),
        t4 as (
            SELECT  id,LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) as autobrazeError1, row_number() over (order by id ) rn
            FROM [leakOpportunities].[dbo].[test_recipe_value] WHERE test_key_id in(1)
        ),
        t5 as (
            SELECT  id,LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) as autobrazeError2, row_number() over (order by id ) rn
            FROM [leakOpportunities].[dbo].[test_recipe_value] WHERE test_key_id in(2)
        )

        SELECT  model_num,revision,value, value-(CAST((value) AS INT) - CAST((autobrazeError1) AS INT)-CAST((autobrazeError2) AS INT)),CAST((value) AS INT) - CAST((autobrazeError1) AS INT)-CAST((autobrazeError2) AS INT)
        FROM t1 full outer join t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
        full outer join t3 on t3.rn = t1.rn
        full outer join t4 on t4.rn = t1.rn
        full outer join t5 on t5.rn = t1.rn
        PRINT 'No Records inserted as the insert record was set to false' 
    END
```

please note in my query i do some extra math and add some extra things. This query doesn't work tho because the way the data is entered not all the records have all the values which makes it so that the "rn" is not a safe way to compare them. For most of them this approach works, but there are some discrepancies.   I also tried using the "test_recipe_id" column as a match but I also got some data discrepancies.

Could someone help me or point me into the right direction on how I could make this right, or maybe a pivot query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need individual CTEs to obtain values using row number over ids.

A simple GROUP BY would suffice, also eliminating the need of JOIN later.

See query below:

```
; with t1 as
(
      select 
        model_num=max(case when test_key_id =23 then LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) end),
        revision =max(case when test_key_id =25 then LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) end),
        [value]  =max(case when test_key_id =24 then LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) end),
        autobrazeError1= max(case when test_key_id =1 then LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) end),
        autobrazeError2= max(case when test_key_id =2 then LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) end)
       from [leakOpportunities].[dbo].[test_recipe_value] 
      group by test_recipe_id
)

select 
    model_num,
    revision,
    [value],
    [value]
        - ISNULL(CAST([value] AS INT),0) 
        - ISNULL(CAST(autobrazeError1 AS INT),0)
        - ISNULL(CAST(autobrazeError2 AS INT),0),
    ISNULL(CAST([value] AS INT),0)
        - ISNULL(CAST(autobrazeError1 AS INT),0)
        - ISNULL(CAST(autobrazeError2 AS INT),0)
from t1
```